# tinyMCE editor doesnt look the same as output

Tags: css, html, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor, and I am using 2 same divs with `float:right;` in the CSS.

The issue I am having is that when I save the HTML, and open the saved content on any browser, it doesn't look the same as in the editor.

As an example I have attached 2 pictures, note there is a difference in the height of the blue boxes (in the editor and in the output).

Editor:

[image: enter example editor]

Output:
[image: enter example browser]

Here is the HTML in the editor:

```
<div class="sub-mw" div="">
1 <br />1<br />1<br />1<br />

<!--@*@TStem1@*@-->
<div id="enews">
<div class="enewstext">News</div>
</div>
<!--@*@TEtem1@*@--> 

<br /><br /><br />

<!--@*@TStem1@*@-->
<div id="enews">
<div class="enewstext">News</div>
</div>
<!--@*@TEtem1@*@-->

1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br /><br />as<br />dasd
<br />asd<br />a<br />da
</div>
```

Also Here is the css used:

```
.enewstext {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: #0163b1;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #FFF;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

#enews{
    background:#3394e1;
    width:18%;
    height:300px;
    float:right;
}
```

**Edit 1:**
In this scenario, tracing the issue, it is caused by the `<br>` tag. It has a smaller height in the tinymce editor than on chrome.

Any Idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: i suggest you give that specific `<br>` a class like **justThisTime** and set its padding or margin as you want.So this will be less browser dependant and act more like you desire.

Comment: Yeah good idea, I have found also that the space between lines is not the same, if u check the 2 pictures above, you will note that there is a small extra space in the output then the editor

Comment: wysiwyg editors do a great job but unfourtunately it is not perfect. Maybe you can put them in a table without borders and put just spaces with `&nbsp` and adjust cells. Just an idea.